# Can cancer cells transmit from one organism to another?

Tags: cell-biology, cancer

I know cancer cells are very resilient, so would it be possible for them to survive outside of the original organism for long enough to be absorbed by another? Furthermore, would that type of "infection" be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Devil facial tumour disease is an example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_facial_tumour_disease

Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonally_transmissible_cancer) for other examples of transmissible cancers.

I have not heard of any human transmissible cancer.